# Send data from a Flash webpage to a C++ application

Tags: c++, flash, html

How can I send a string from a Flash webpage (from browser) to a local C++ application without using AIR, a browser extension or a plugin? I just want a one-way communication - send only. Any ideas?

Comment: Use [sockets](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html) or websockets.

Comment: Aren't Sockets for online connection only?
I just need communication from the flash running locally on the browser to a C++ application on the same PC (Windows).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not show what has been tried.

Comment: You can use sockets on localhost, no need to go online.